# Input stream error with boost serialization

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I am trying to load serialized content and I have been unable to solve the issue. I have boiled it down to a specific line of code. I tried to minimize the code as best as possible but also show some debugging. The class `loadAudi` is only there to illustrate where the error is coming from and serves only the purpose of helping debugging the problem. The line `ar& audi` in `loadAudi` is what is causing the error. In the "real" code, the `ar& audi` right after `boost::archive::binary_iarchive ar(in_f);` is what is causing the problem.  Here is the code (complete output is at the bottom):

```
#include <armadillo>

#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/void_cast_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class Engine
{
public:
    Engine () {}
    Engine (const int cyl) : _cyl ( cyl ) {}
    int getCyl () const { return _cyl; }

private:
    int _cyl;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & _cyl;
    }
};

class Car {
public:
    virtual char const* type() const = 0;
    virtual void printMember () const = 0;
    virtual void save (const std::string file) const { std::cout << "file" << std::endl; };

    virtual ~Car() = default;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {};
};

class Audi : public Car, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Car> {
public:

Audi() {};
Audi(const std::string owner, const int hp,const unsigned int cyl)
    : _owner ( owner ),
    _hp    ( hp ),
    _eng          ( std::make_shared<Engine>(cyl) )
{ }

char const* type() const override { return "Audi"; }

void printMember () const override
{
    std::cout
    << this->type() << ":\n"
    << "owner: " << _owner
    << " hp: " << _hp
    << " engine: " << _eng->getCyl()
    << std::endl;
}
void save (const std::string file) const {
    std::ofstream of(file, std::ofstream::binary);
    std::stringstream strs;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(of);
    std::shared_ptr<const Car> audi = shared_from_this();
    boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&audi, sizeof(audi));
}

private:
std::string  _owner;
int          _hp;
std::shared_ptr<Engine> _eng;

friend class boost::serialization::access;
template <class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Car>(*this);
    ar & _owner;
    ar & _hp;
    ar & _eng;
}
};

Audi& loadAudi (const std::string file_name) {
std::cout << "Loading " << file_name << std::endl;
std::ifstream in_f(file_name, std::ifstream::binary);

std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
std::shared_ptr<Car> audi; //= std::make_unique<Audi>();

std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
boost::archive::binary_iarchive ar(in_f);

std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
ar& audi;

std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
return dynamic_cast<Audi &>(*audi);
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Audi);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Engine);
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Car); //Tell Boost that Car is abstract

int main() {
std::string save_file = "test.dat";
std::ofstream of(save_file, std::ofstream::binary);
std::ifstream in_f(save_file, std::ifstream::binary);
{
    std::shared_ptr<Car> audi = std::make_shared<Audi>("Wilma", 3, 16);
    audi->printMember();

    std::stringstream strs;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(of);
    ar& audi;

    // audi_save_dir = strs.str();
    std::cout << "Count of audi:" << audi.use_count() << std::endl;

    ar << boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&audi, sizeof(audi));
}


{
    std::shared_ptr<Car> audi; //= std::make_unique<Audi>();
    std::cout << "Deserialize: Count of audi:" << audi.use_count() << std::endl;

    //std::stringstream strs(f);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ar(in_f);
    ar& audi;
    Audi& d = dynamic_cast<Audi &>(*audi);

    std::cout << "Deserialize: Count of audi:" << audi.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Print Audi:" << std::endl;
    d.printMember();
}


std::shared_ptr<Car> audi = std::make_shared<Audi>("Daniel", 200, 8);
audi->printMember();

std::string test_dat = "my-new-audi.dat";
audi->save(test_dat);
Audi& d =  loadAudi(test_dat);
d.printMember();

return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
Audi:
owner: Wilma hp: 3 engine: 16
Count of audi:1
Deserialize: Count of audi:0
Deserialize: Count of audi:2
Print Audi:
Audi:
owner: Wilma hp: 3 engine: 16
Audi:
owner: Daniel hp: 200 engine: 8
Loading my-new-audi.dat
1
2
3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
what():  input stream error
[2]    29888 abort      ./a.out
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 issues here.

1. You did not serialize `audi` object inside `save` method by `ar << audi` call.
2. You return a reference to `audi` object from `loadAudi` function. This object you are referencing to is destroyed right after you exit the function.

Comment: Hi otter, thanks for the insight.
1. Are you referring to the BMW `save` function? If so, you are right. But the Audi class does have the `audi` in the save function. I just updated the code so that BMW class `save` function shows the audi addition. Would this solve the first issue?

2. But the pointer is a smart point and one can transfer the ownership of it, right?

Comment: 1. In `main` function `audi->save(test_dat);` but there is no actual saving inside `save` method. The thing that you are doing with `ar& audi` call. 2. You can transfer ownership by moving or copying smart pointer itself, not by reference the internals of the smart pointer.

Comment: 1. What do you purpose? `boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&audi, sizeof(audi));` does serialize audi...or at least I thought it did.

Comment: Please don't use binary_objects at all here. `binary_oarchive ar; ar& audi` is serialization code. And `binary_iarchive ar; ar& audi` is deserialization. With `template <class Archive> void serialize` being serialization function.

Comment: Ok I removed `boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&audi, sizeof(audi));` and `/ar << boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&audi, sizeof(audi));` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Hi @otter do you have any other suggestion? I've been working on this for a while and still haven't figured it out.

Comment: Just do 2 things I stated in the answer: 1. Write `ar << audi` in the end of `save` method. 2. Return `Audi` (not `Audi&`) from `loadAudi` function. These 2 changes are the minimum you can to to get the code to work.

Comment: Hi @otter ok I somehow thought ar& audi wouldn't work in the `save` function. 2.How would I exactly return `Audi` from `loadAudi`? It's a dynamic cast and in the "<>" it needs to be either a pointer or a reference.

Comment: `Audi loadAudi` in function signature.